# In Scala, is Int a super-type of List[Int] and how so?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, fold

Taking a look at this example:

```
val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) 
val sum = list.fold(0)((x, y) => x + y) 
assert(sum == 15)
```

And the method signature of `fold`:

```
fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1
```

Am assuming `A` is type `List[Int]` and `A1` is type `Int`.
According to the [official docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html) for `fold`, `A1` is `a type parameter for the binary operator, a supertype of A`. If my assumption above is correct, then `Int` is a super-type of `List[Int]` in the above sum example. Some blog posts like [this one](https://coderwall.com/p/4l73-a/scala-fold-foldleft-and-foldright) actually state this explicitly.
Clearly, `List[Int]` does not extend `Int`. So my question: Is `Int` a super-type of `List[Int]` and how so?

Comment: That blog you referenced is horribly wrong

Comment: But the blog does not mention anything even hinting towards horribly wrong claims like `Int is a super-type of List[Int]`.

Comment: @sarveshseri only it does, do check the last sentence of the 3rd last paragraph

Comment: It just says that `in all three folds the type of the start value must be the same as the return value`, which is a correct statement. This much is pretty clear from the signatures themselves - for any `List[A]` you have three "folding" methods - `fold[A1 >: A](z: A1)(op: (A1, A1) => A1): A1`, `foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B`, and `foldRight[B](z: B)(op: (A, B) => B): B`. As you can see, the return types are exactly same as the collector/start-value types. I don't see anything even remotely suggesting that `Int is a super-type of List[Int]`.

Comment: Ok. Now I see it. It does say that `Int is a supertype of List[Int]`... Weird that it escaped me when I read it last time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `A` is the type variable bound in the `List[+A]` type constructor itself: it's towards the top of the documentation page that you linked, in

```
sealed abstract class List[+A]
```

Your `list`-variable is of type `List[Int]`, so `A` is `Int`. The `A1` in `fold` must be a supertype of `Int`, in this case, both `A` and `A1 >: A` are therefore just `Int` (not `List[Int]`)

---

Regarding the link to the blog: it indeed includes the sentence

> Int is a supertype of List[Int]

This is plain wrong. You can easily check this as follows:

```
scala> implicitly[List[Int] <:< Int]
                 ^
       error: Cannot prove that List[Int] <:< Int.
```